# XQUERY: How to use all elements in a directory to transform

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I am building an app, where I need to transform all files in what is $xml below from xml to html, with a certain xslt, obviously. Then I want them to be output as `<li> <!-- the transformed output --> </li>`

```
  declare function app:XMLtoHTML-forAll ($node as node(), $model as map(*), $query as xs:string?){
    let $ref := xs:string(request:get-parameter("document", ""))
    let $xml := doc(concat("/db/apps/BookOfOrders/data/edition/",$ref))
    let $xsl := doc("/db/apps/BookOfOrders/resources/xslt/xmlToHtml.xsl")
    let $params :=
    <parameters>
       {for $p in request:get-parameter-names()
        let $val := request:get-parameter($p,())
        where  not($p = ("document","directory","stylesheet"))
        return
           <param name="{$p}"  value="{$val}"/>
       }
    </parameters>
       for $doc in collection("/db/apps/BookOfOrders/data/edition")/tei:TEI

            return

            <li> {transform:transform($xml, $xsl, $params)} </li>
    };
```

My function, however, returns empty `<li></li>`-elements for every document, I have in this folder. 
Can anyone hint me towards what I am doing wrong?

Small Edit: it also does not use all files, but only what seems to be randomly pick one and transform this over and over ...

Answer (score 1):

I would first verify what is being assigned to `$xml`

```
let $xml := doc(concat("/db/apps/BookOfOrders/data/edition/",$ref))
```

and compare that to what is being assigned to `$doc` in your for loop:

```
for $doc in collection("/db/apps/BookOfOrders/data/edition")/tei:TEI
```

Why iterate through each `$doc` and then transform the same `$xml`?

```
<li> {transform:transform($xml, $xsl, $params)} </li>
```

Did you intend to transform the `$doc` instead? Maybe also use the `$ref` to construct the collection URI??

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't bei able to check just now. I think I should do transform:transform($doc, $xsl, $params). Until Then: thanks a Lot for your thoughts :)

Comment: You were absolutely right about transforming ```$doc``` instead of ```$xml```. Now I see that the files are not transformed by order, but by sth. else. Probably time of adding to the DB or sth. similar.